# Fail to read numeric matrix (without including data in square brackets) from a text file to CPLEX IloNumArray2

Tags: c++, cplex

I am using CPLEX C++ concert library to model some mixed integer problem. When it comes to reading data from external text file. I have been always using the template operator >> to read numeric values from a text file in the format of [x, y, z, ...] (likewise, [  [x1, y1, c1, ...], [x2, y2, c2, ...], ...] for a 2D case). This way is fine. However, in order to make my code more generic, I wanted to write a function which can read a numeric matrix without formatted using square brackets (i.e. pure numeric matrix, see example below) from a text file into a IloNumArray2 directly.

Below it a sample data text file I used, called "test.txt":

0.51  3.71  0.23
0.90  3.71  0.24
1.30  3.71  0.24
1.45  3.34  0.18
2.15  3.77  0.15

Note that this matrix could have any number of columns (usually 2 or 3), you may know the total number of rows ahead of time. Let's suppose we know the total number of rows. I give my reading data function and partial code in main.cpp where I called that reading data function as follows.

```
void readToIloNumArray(IloEnv env, const char* fileName, IloNumArray2& iloNum2dArray)
    {
        std::ifstream inFile(fileName); 
        if(!inFile) 
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: could not open data file '" << fileName <<endl;
            exit(1);
        }

        IloNumArray rowData(env);  // to store each line of data 
        std::string line; 
        int i = 0; 

        while(std::getline(inFile, line))  // read a line of data as a string
        {
            std::istringstream iss(line); 
            double number; 
            rowData.clear();    // to clear the 1-d array before reading new data to it

            while(iss >> number)  // extract numbers from line
            {
                rowData.add(number); 
            }

            // This is how I add each rowData (an IloNumArray) to the final iloNum2dArray (an IloNumArray2) 
            iloNum2dArray[i] = rowData;

            // output iloNum2dArray[i] to make sure it contains the correct data
            cout << iloNum2dArray[i] << endl;  // yes, results is correct

            // by changing the index i, I ensure that the next line of data is stored as a new row in iloNum2Array 
            i++; 
        }

        // make sure that the number of lines read from the text file is actually equal to its known actual size
        cout << "i = " << i << endl;  // YES
        // SOMEHOW, each row of iloNum2dArray just simply repeats the last row of the input text file
        cout << iloNum2dArray << endl; 
        cout << "Successfully read file " << fileName << "!" << endl;
        inFile.close();
    }

#include <ilcplex/ilocplex.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    IloEnv env;
    IloNumArray2 IloMatrix(env, n);

    // call the reading data function defined above
    readToIloNumArray(env, "test.txt", IloMatrix); 

    // output IloMatrix to see if it contains the original matrix in the test.txt
    cout << "IloMatrix = " << IloMatrix << endl;  // NO, IloMatrix repeats the last line for n times        // do other process 
    ...
}
```

My question is why the final IloMatrix doesn't contain the original matrix specified in the test.txt file, but repeating the last line of data of the test.txt for n times? (shown as below)

2.15  3.77  0.15
2.15  3.77  0.15
2.15  3.77  0.15
2.15  3.77  0.15
2.15  3.77  0.15

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround method, which first used a 2D vector to store the matrix read from the text file. Then, simply copy (assign values of) that 2D vector to IloNumArray2. Modified reading data function code is given below:

```
void readToIloNumArray(IloEnv env, const char* fileName, IloNumArray2& iloNum2dArray)
{
    ifstream inFile(fileName); 
    if(!inFile) 
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: could not open data file '" << fileName <<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    vector<vector<double> > vectorMatrix;
    string line; 

    while(getline(inFile, line))  // read a line 
    {
        vector<double> rowData;
        istringstream iss(line); 
        double number; 
        while(iss >> number)  // extract numbers from line
        {
            rowData.push_back(number); 
        }
        vectorMatrix.push_back(rowData); 
    }

    // Now assign  values (copy) vectorMatrix to IloNumArray2
    for(int i = 0; i < vectorMatrix.size(); i++)
    {
        iloNum2dArray.add(IloNumArray(env)); 
        for(int j = 0; j < vectorMatrix[0].size(); j++)
        {
            iloNum2dArray[i].add(vectorMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /// for debug
    //cout << "IloNum2dArray:" << iloNum2dArray << endl; 
    cout << "Successfully read file " << fileName << "!" << endl;
    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: This is a plain C++ I/O question, doesn't seem related to CPLEX at all other than purely incidentally?

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick, thanks for your comment. It would be a pure C++ I/O question if I just asked help on how to read a numeric matrix from a text file into a 2D array or vector. As I stated in my question title, I was searching for solution than can directly read the matrix into IloNumArray2 data type in CPLEX. Noted that my solution above is only a  work-around, i.e. not solving the problem I stated in my question.